# Oneapi fatal error: compare: No such file or directory after system restart

Tags: tbb, intel-oneapi

I have a project been working on for my research for over a year, Oneapi have been integrated for way longer than 6months, everything working and all. Yesterday I updated some test code, and ran the tests, nothing out of normal. Today I restarted my machine (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64bits) for updates, and now when I try to compile the project it gives:

```
In file included from /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.2.0/env/../include/oneapi/tbb/enumerable_thread_specific.h:26,
                 from /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.2.0/env/../include/oneapi/tbb/combinable.h:22,
                 from /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.2.0/env/../include/oneapi/tbb.h:35,
                 from ...file name omitted for privacy...
/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.2.0/env/../include/oneapi/tbb/concurrent_vector.h:33:10: fatal error: compare: No such file or directory
   33 | #include <compare>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

This only happened after system restart (possibly broke some links?) and only happens in files that require concurrent_vector.h

Ideally I'd prefer a fix that won't require reinstall of oneapi, `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade` didn't fix it, neither did restarting the system again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ran into the same thing. It looks as if TBB automatically includes `<compare>` if you are compiling with `-std=c++20`:

https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/9e15720bc7744f85dff611d34d65e9099e077da4/include/oneapi/tbb/detail/_config.h#L253

```
#define __TBB_CPP20_COMPARISONS_PRESENT                 __TBB_CPP20_PRESENT
```

GCC only [added the compare header in libstdc++-10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

To me, this looks like a bug in TBB. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/379).

As a hotfix, I was able to downgrade my project to C++17. If that is not an option, you could consider copying `detail/_config.h`, defining `__TBB_CPP20_COMPARISONS_PRESENT 0` in your copy and including it before you include any TBB header. The include guards should make sure that your version supersedes the broken TBB version.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. Downgrading to  C++17 worked.